# Not able to access application.yml properties in springboot component

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-mvc, yaml

I have an `application.yml` file which contains properties as below

```
NAME:
   CLASS:
     ID: ABC123456
```

and here is my spring boot component class

```
import lombok.extern.slf4j.Slf4j;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

@Component
@Slf4j
public class  ProcessMe {

@Value("${NAME.CLASS.ID}")
String StuId;

public boolean IsRightOrWrong(){
    System.out.println(StuId);
}
}
```

In above componenent `System.out.println(StuId);` is always coming as null. When i am tying to call this function using Junit test class. What's wrong in the above code?

Comment: can you show the main class and this complete class including package structure as well ? and also path of application.yml

Comment: @Deadpool I have added the package and my application.yml file is located inside `resources` folder of application

Answer (score 1):

I suppose this solution to define in constructor like

```
@Component
@Slf4j
public class  ProcessMe {

String StuId;

@Autowired
ProcessMe(@Value("${NAME.CLASS.ID}") String StuId) {
    this.StuId = StuId;
}
public boolean IsRightOrWrong(){
    System.out.println(this.StuId);
}
}
```

Hope useful

Comment: When tried to execute the test case, getting `org.mockito.exceptions.base.MockitoException: Unable to initialize @Spy annotated field 'result'.` How to get rid of this?

Comment: @Lara I need to see code for answer you for this question if I can

Answer (score 0):

If you can start the application then I believe that your configuration is correct. I mean that `StuId` have some value.

The problem is how you testing `When i am tying to call this function using Junit test class. What's wrong in the above code?`

It seems that you're calling from the unit test. Then you need to clone application.yaml to test profile then your test container can read data, otherwise you have to mock your configuration.

btw: Java Object property should using camel case lol